# Need to concatenate object name with counter variable properly

Tags: javascript

I am working on this demo. How I can Concatenate the `years.range` with `counter` to have `years.range2[0]`?

```js
let years = {
  range1: [200, 2001, 2002, 2003],
  range2: [2004, 2005, 206, 2007]
}

//$('#year').html(years.range1[0]);
let counter = 1;
$('#year').html(years.range + counter + [0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="year"></div>
```

Comment: what the result you are looking for?

Comment: range is an array so you can index on it, try it like this `years.range[counter]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to access the `range2` item from the `years` range object:

```
let years = {
  range1: [200, 2001, 2002, 2003],
  range2: [2004, 2005, 206, 2007]
}

const counter = 2  // <--- gets you `years['range2']` when concatenated

$('#year').html(years[`range${counter}`][0]);
```

By you doing this: `$('#year').html(years.range + counter + [0]);`

the issue is that `years.range + counter` would give you the proper array index but `+[0]` would mess things up since you are saying add `years.range1` with an array containing single element - `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic property access requires `[` ... `]` :

```
 years["range" + counter][0]
```

But why is `years` not an array? That would make the while thing way easier.

```
 const years = [
    [200,2001,2002,2003],
[2004,2005,206,2007]
];

console.log(years[0]);
```